# How do I create elevatedbuttons over image in flutter?

Tags: flutter, button, background

I have a boxdecoration with an image as my background, how do I place elevatedbuttons over it, like windows icons in a desktop?

Comment: Please share your code attempt, so we could assist you.

Comment: Hi Muhammad Hussain, I kept searching and trying different aproaches and im using stack with a Positioned() for the background color and another Positioned() on top with the image. Than I created a Scafold() on top with the TextFields and buttons.

Comment: Hi, I see, can you share your code here? Just paste it here and then I can help you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get my result using a stack for my background with 02 positioned and then a scaffold for the foreground with the remaining widgets.

```
class _IngredientesState extends State<Ingredientes> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Ingrediente ing = Ingrediente();
    if (_loading == true) {
      ing.init();
      _loading = false;
    }
    final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned(
          child: SizedBox(
            width: width,
            child: Container(
              color: cBakcGroundColor,
              width: width,
              height: height,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          top: 100,
          child: Opacity(
            opacity: 0.2,
            child: Image(
              width: width,
              image: const AssetImage(cBackgroundLogo),
            ),
          ),    
        ),
        const Foreground()
      ],
    );
  }
}

class Foreground extends StatefulWidget {
  const Foreground({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Foreground> createState() => _ForegroundState();
}

class _ForegroundState extends State<Foreground> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18),
        child: DefaultTextStyle(
          style: GoogleFonts.oxygen(
              color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20, fontWeight:     FontWeight.w500),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              const SizedBox(height: 50),
              const Text('Nome do Ingrediente'),
              const SizedBox(height: 5),
              TextField(
                controller: _ingrediente,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: outlineInputBorder,
                    enabledBorder: outlineInputBorder,
                    focusedBorder: outlineInputBorder,
                    hintText: 'Ex.: Farinha de trigo.'),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              const Text('Quantidade'),
              const SizedBox(height: 5),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: width * 0.5,
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: _iquantidade,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                        FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                      ],
                      textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: outlineInputBorder,
                        enabledBorder: outlineInputBorder,
                        focusedBorder: outlineInputBorder,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: width * 0.2,
                    child: Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                        border: Border.all(
                            color: cBorderColor,
                            style: BorderStyle.solid,
                            width: 0.80),
                      ),    
                      child: DropdownButton(
                        value: unidadeSelecionada,
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
                        items: unidadeIngrediente.map((String items) {
                          return DropdownMenuItem(
                            value: items,
                            child: Text(items),
                          );
                        }).toList(),
                        onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                          setState(() {
                            unidadeSelecionada = newValue!;
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              const Text('Valor pago'),
              const SizedBox(height: 5),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: width * 0.5,
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: _ipreco,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                        FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                      ],
                      textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: outlineInputBorder,
                        enabledBorder: outlineInputBorder,
                        focusedBorder: outlineInputBorder,
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),    
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: BuildSaveButton(context),
    );
  }
}
```